# nodejs modio api "add modfile" failing to upload

Tags: node.js, api

Im trying to upload modfiles with the api but it keeps saying that Im not including filedata. Ive tried with fetch like in the [docs](https://docs.mod.io/?javascript--nodejs#add-modfileq) but it just gives the same error. If I try http it just gives a list of the files as if it was a GET request.

```js
    var zip = `./mod.zip`; // it exists!
        var body = {
            //filedata: `@${zip}`,
            filedata: fs.readFileSync(zip, `binary`),
            //filehash: crypto.createHash('md5').update(fs.readFileSync(zip, `binary`)).digest('hex'),
            //version: version,
            //active: active,
            //changelog: changelog,
            //metadata_blob: meta,
        };
        var res = await fetch(`https://api.mod.io/v1/games/${config.modio.gameid}/mods/${config.modio.modid}/files`, { // actually HTTP
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.modio.token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        });
        //console.log(body.filedata);
        res = await res.json();
        if (res.error)
            console.log(res.error);
        else
            console.log(res);
```

```json
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 422,
            "error_ref": 13009,
            "message": "Validation Failed. Please see below to fix invalid input:",
            "errors": {
                "filedata": "The filedata field is required when upload id is not present.",
                "upload_id": "The upload id field is required when filedata is not present."
            }
        }
    }
```

Yes, ive submitted a bug report to them already, twice. Now they are ghosting me. (I'll probably submit a link to this as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They replied!

```
Hi

As mentioned, you would need to send data using FormData, not JSON. 

You can find details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Thanks,
Danny King
Developer Relations Specialist
```

So, I remade my code

```js
const https = require(`https`);
var crypto = require('crypto');
var FormData = require('form-data');

function ObjectToForm(obj = {}) {
    var form = new FormData();
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        var val = obj[key];
        switch (typeof val) {
            case `boolean`:
                val = String(val);
                break;
        }
        form.append(key, val);
    });
    return form;
}

        if (fs.statSync(zip).size > 5368709120) return consolelog(`Zip bigger then 5gb`);
        var body = {
            filedata: fs.createReadStream(zip),
            filehash: crypto.createHash('md5').update(fs.readFileSync(zip)).digest('hex'),
            version: version,
            active: active,
            changelog: changelog,
            metadata_blob: meta,
        };
        var form = ObjectToForm(body);

        var options = {
            hostname: 'api.mod.io',
            port: 443,
            path: `/v1/games/${config.modio.gameid}/mods/${config.modio.modid}/files`,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.modio.token}`,
                ...form.getHeaders(),
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
        };

        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            var data = [];
            res.on('data', (d) => data.push(d));
            req.on(`close`, () => {
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
                var resp = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
                if (resp.error)
                    console.log(resp.error);
                else if (res.statusCode == 201)
                    r(true);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(`Error publishing:`);
            console.log(e);
            r(e);
        });

        form.pipe(req)
            .on(`close`, () => req.end());
```

And it worked. Thanks King.